# How do I handle if the api error message is undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If the login is successful, I do not receive an error message. My problem is that if no error message is received, the value of data.error.message is undefined and the program crashes. How can I solve this?

```
 if(data.error.message === 'EMAIL_NOT_FOUND'){
      setError({
        title: "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND",
        message: "This email address is not registered.",
      });
      setIsLoading(false);
      return;
    }
```

```
    if(data.error.message === 'EMAIL_NOT_FOUND' && data.error.message !== undefined){
      setError({
        title: "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND",
        message: "This email address is not registered.",
      });
      setIsLoading(false);
      return;
    }
```

I tried this too but same error.

Comment: Are you sure data,error.message is undefined ? Maybe data.error is undefined in your case.

Comment: If the login is successful, no error message comes from the server and therefore the data.error.message is undefined. If there is an error message, it works. However, I want to handle both cases.

Comment: Could you try this ? if(data !== undefined && data.error !== undefined && data.error.message === 'EMAIL_NOT_FOUND')

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably you getting error because you are trying to read from object that is undefined.

You can make modify your condition to handle case when `error` is undefined:

```
 if(data?.error?.message && data.error.message === 'EMAIL_NOT_FOUND'){
   ...
 }
```

That way you will make sure that `error` and `message` exist and not undefined.

Comment: Its javascript without typescript actually. Just try this in your browser console and see it works

Comment: Sorry. You're right. Please just do a simple edit so I can undo my vote.